# How do I disable drag event on iScroll?

Tags: iscroll

The structure of `iScroll` is this "

```
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="left_arrow">
            <img class="img_left" src="images/a_right.png">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation_scroller">
            <ul id="navigation_list">
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="house_disposition.htm"></a></li>
            <ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right_arrow">
            <img class="img_left" src="images/a_right.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the requirement is disable to drag iscroll, the only way to scroll `#navigation_scroller` is to click `.left_arrow` or `.right_arrow`.

And the visible `<li>` in iscroll at most have 5.

If  `<li>` is less than 5, just disable all the way to scroll `#navigation_scroller`.

When `<li>` is greater than 5, disable drag **iscroll**, just move the `<li>` left/right one by one by click `.left_arrow/right_arrow`

---

There are two problems.

1. How to disable drag on **iscroll** ? I find nothing setting about this
2. How to scroll `<li>` one by one ? Is it possible by calling `scrollToElement` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation does not list some, but iScroll v5.1.1 has extra options, like:

- mouseWheel
- disableMouse
- disablePointer
- disableTouch

You can set all of them to false/true and no interaction with mouse, touchpad our touching screen wont be processed.

To change slides with arrows, you can use these methods:

- next()
- prev()

or better

- goToPage( x, y )

To slide from page to page, you should set snap option to match elements you describe as page. In your case options could look like this:

```
var options = {
    snap: 'li', // your page selector
    snapThreshold: 0.1,
    mouseWheel: false,
    disableMouse: true,
    disablePointer: true,
    disableTouch: true
};

var scroll = new IScroll('#navigation_scroller', options);
```

Now just attach events on arrows to call `scroller.goToPage(x, y)` accordingly.
X and Y represents "page" number (in your case `<li>` order number). To get current page position, you should read `scroller.currentPage.pageY` or `scroller.currentPage.pageX` accordingly.

This should help you achieve your desired behaviour of your project.